# Laravel Socilite is not working on Amazon EC2

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2

I am using Amazon ubuntu 16 server and I have hosted the laravel application, Everything works fine except login with socialite plugin for facebook login.  The same thing is running on my local , And I have changed the correct `request_uri` on developers account as well as `.env` But this is not working on amazon server.

I have also check for curl, that is working.

I am getting the following error

```
Error creating resource: [message] fopen(https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/oauth/access_token): failed to open stream: Connection timed out
[file] /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php
[line] 324
```

Thanks advance ... for giving the exact solution..

Comment: Does it happen all the time?

Comment: yes, it happens all the time ..

Comment: Seems like a network problem. I recommend you searching around the [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/search.jspa?mbtc=b60b34394ddbaa9543a88861c7a5a06b3cf50d9d601fb5a2e397b1d832aa6e45&threadID=&q=graph.facebook.com&objID=f30&userID=&dateRange=all&numResults=15&rankBy=9).

Comment: It seems permission issue. Add this permission to your www directory.
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

Comment: I have tried this , but still the same issue..

Comment: @Camilo , I saw the comments over network issue, but what can I do for the same, should I change the region ..?

Comment: I would try it.